# How to check if string of HTML is safe?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, xpath

In my application I need to send and receive HTML in string form. I'd like to keep things safe, and because of that I need to check if dom elements in the string match allowed tags as well as if the style declarations are valid, and if there are no injected scripts. First thing that comes to mind is of course regexing the string, but this is tedious, might be buggy and for sure inefficient. Second idea is using something called XPath, but even though I've read some materials on MDN site, I still have no idea how to implement this sample code:

```
const XPathResult           = Components.interfaces.nsIDOMXPathResult;

const ALLOWED_TAGS          = ['div', 'span', 'b', 'i', 'u', 'br', 'font', 'img'];
const ALLOWED_STYLES        = ['font-weight', 'font-size', 'font-family', 'text-decoration', 'color', 'background-color'];
const ALLOWED_ATTRIBUTES    = ['style', 'name'];

const XPATH_PART_TAGS = ALLOWED_TAGS.map(function (v) {
    return "name() != '" + v + "' and name() != '" + v.toUpperCase() + "'"; // case insensitive
}).join(' and ');

const XPATH_PART_ATTRS = ALLOWED_ATTRIBUTES.map(function (v) {
    return "name() != '" + v + "' and name() != '" + v.toUpperCase() + "'"; // case insensitive
}).join(' and ');


const XPATH_BAD_TAGS        = "//*[(namespace-uri() != 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml') or (" + XPATH_PART_TAGS + ")]";
const XPATH_BAD_ATTRIBUTES  = "//@*[((namespace-uri() != 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml') and (namespace-uri() != '')) or (" + XPATH_PART_ATTRS+ ")]";
const XPATH_STYLE           = "//@*[name() = 'style']";


/**
 * Checks if inline style definition is considered secure
 *
 * @param {String} styleValue value of style attribute
 * @return bool
 */
function isStyleSecure(styleValue) {
    var styles = styleValue.split(';'),
        style,
        name, value,
        i, l;
    for (i = 0, l = styles.length; i < l; i++) {
        style = styles[i].trim();
        if (style === '') {
            continue;
        }
        style = style.split(':', 2);
        if (style.length !== 2) {
            return false;
        }
        name = style[0].trim().toLowerCase();
        value = style[1].trim();

        if (ALLOWED_STYLES.indexOf(name) === -1) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

/**
 * Singleton that verifies if given XHTML document fragment is considered secure.
 * Uses whitelist-based checks on tag names, attribute names and document namespaces.
 *
 * @class
 * @namespace core.SecurityFilter.MessageSecurityFilter
 */
var MessageSecurityFilter = {
    /**
     * Checks if given document fragment is safe
     *
     * @param {nsIDOMElement} element root element of the XHTML document fragment to analyze
     * @return {bool} true if fragment is safe, false otherwise
     */
    isSecure: function SecurityFilter_isSecure(element) {
        var document = element.ownerDocument,
            result,
            attr;

        result = document.evaluate('//*', element, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null);

        result = document.evaluate(XPATH_BAD_TAGS, element, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null);
        if (result.iterateNext()) {
            return false;
        }
        result = document.evaluate(XPATH_BAD_ATTRIBUTES, element, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null);
        if ((attr = result.iterateNext())) {
            return false;
        }

        result = document.evaluate(XPATH_STYLE, element, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null);
        while ((attr = result.iterateNext())) {
            if (!isStyleSecure(attr.nodeValue)) {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }

};
```

And the first idea was to create documentFragment, and then check it's nodes with either treeWalker or just following dom tree with .firstChild etc. But I guess this solution is unsafe as it will leave me opened to all injected scripts. Am I right?

Is there any other way ?

Comment: Make sure you are doing the same thing on the server side...

Comment: The problem with writing your own HTML purifier is most of the time people try to scrub valid HTML, but browsers are set up to deal with invalid SGML, so there are many holes that exist where a user could be uploading something that seems like invalid HTML, but actually works, which your purifier never caught.  It's best to adopt one that is already in the community and if you feel you found a hole, submit an update - help everyone out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't roll your own sanitizer.  Use one that has been written by someone who knows the dark ugly corners of HTML, CSS, and JS.

See http://code.google.com/p/google-caja/wiki/JsHtmlSanitizer for a JavaScript sanitizer.

Answer (score 0):

The level of security you need depends on how you are processing the HTML. If you are sending it via email or displaying it on a web server, you need to be a lot more careful than if you're just doing text analysis on it.

Assuming you are displaying this on a web server, this is a very hard problem, and you should use an HTML purifier such as http://htmlpurifier.org/ and **subscribe to the security updates**, perhaps even find a way to automatically take updates. For extra security, *also* use an iframe. Also pay special attention if you're escaping the HTML somehow.

Of course the right answer could be completely different depending on the actual context of your problem. The above should handle the most common case.

Also see [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)